# How to find process which flood the whole network

Tags: linux, networking, process

I have a laptop with Fedora 21 and TP-Link router with DD-WRT software. Sometimes my whole internet stops for any device. When I reboot my laptop or just I turn off wireless, the internet works fine. In this time when my laptop flood my network upload data with 100-150 kb/s. How can I find which process does that and why?

Answer (score 1):

The `jnettop` package may provide the information you're looking for; however the command `netstat -anp` will simply show you what processes are connected to a socket - it won't tell you how much data is being sent, but may help in identifying processes you're not expecting to be connected to anything.